# Maintain HTML video quality

Tags: html, css, html5-video, videoquality

So i have written this code and I need help in maintaining the quality of the video when I make it take up the entire screen. The video I add is a link from a site (originally i wanted to add a video from my local storage but wasn't showing so I gave that up.)
The quality drops (obviously) when its stretched across the screen so I need help in managing quality.

The CSS

```css
    body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
  font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
 video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:100% !important;
  z-index: 1;/*  object-fit is not supported on IE  */
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
 
                 <video autoplay muted loop>    
                  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/368320203.sd.mp4?s=38b1bac5d627b94fb902597643461ee5f233d00a&amp;profile_id=139&amp;oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">                 </video>
                 
                 <div class="container">
                   <span style="font-size: 63px">Anomaly Detection Portal</span> 
                     <span>
                       <h4>
                          Use our state-of-the-art technology to find out anomalies in your traffic videos.

                       </h4>
                       <h5>
                        Our futuristic models give the maximum accuracy in more than 90% of the cases.
                       </h5>
                      </span>
                     <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="login" role="button">Proceed Ahead.</a>
                 </div>
                   <!-- /.container -->
                 </div>
                 <!-- /.jumbotron -->
```

Comment: its not an issue that can be solved by coding but of the video itself. If the video is smaller then the screen it will be stretched. The only solutions are either to use a video with better resolution or not to nuse full screen and maintaining the video-size with the use of max-width/height.

Comment: @tacoshy but how do i get a video that suits my needs? i mean the videos if played in fullscreen are full HD but when I embed them in my page they get so bad. I could simply add up videos from my storage (got 100+ in my dataset) but they don't show up at all.

Comment: upload the video to your webspace a browser wont be able toto access your harddrive (with tiny exeption of limited cookie and localStorage function). It would be a huge security flaw and performance flaw if a browser could access someone elses harddrive. As such move the video (a copy) to your webspace and link it correctly like any other resources